# display Array within ul li tags

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array that looks like this and I want to display it in a more readable format. I would like the bird name (Gray Hawk etc) and then each listing (which the number of result will vary. This is the code I currently have:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($noteable);
$result = array();
foreach ($xml->result->sighting as $sighting) {
    $location = (string) $sighting->{'loc-name'};
    $bird = (string) $sighting->{'com-name'};
    $howMany = (string) $sighting->{'how-many'};
    $obsdt = (string) $sighting->{'obs-dt'};
           $thenotedate = $obsdt;
       $thenotedate = split('T',$thenotedate);
       $thenotedate = $thenotedate[0];
       $thenotedate = strftime('%a %b %e at %I:%M %p',strtotime($thenotedate)); 

ksort($result);

   if (!isset($result[$bird])) $result[$bird] = array();
    $result[$bird][] = $howMany . ' seen at ' . $location . ' on ' . $thenotedate;
}
print"<pre>";   
print_r($result);
print"</pre>";
 }
```

And this is the array

```
[Gray Hawk] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1 seen at Florida Canyon--lower on Sun Jun  2 at 04:50 PM
        [1] => 1 seen at Madera Canyon--Whitehouse Picnic area on Sat Jun  1 at 07:30 AM
        [2] => 1 seen at Florida Canyon--lower on Thu May 30 at 07:56 AM
        [3] => 1 seen at Florida Canyon--lower on Wed May 29 at 07:40 AM
        [4] => 1 seen at Florida Canyon--lower on Wed May 29 at 07:37 AM
        [5] => 1 seen at Madera Canyon--Madera Picnic Area on Tue May 28 at 04:45 PM
        [6] => 1 seen at Madera Canyon--Proctor Rd. on Mon May 27 at 09:40 AM
    )

[MacGillivray's Warbler] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1 seen at Madera Canyon--Proctor Rd. on Sat May 25 at 05:45 PM
        [1] => 1 seen at Madera Canyon--Proctor Rd. on Sat May 25 at 05:45 PM
        [2] => 1 seen at Madera Canyon--Proctor Rd. on Sat May 25 at 05:30 PM
    )
```

Comment: what's your question? it looks like you know how to use `foreach` and how to output html tags. do you need anything else?

Comment: everytime I try to foreach $result I only get the first bird/sighting..can't figure out how to echo out them all..sorry i'm actually really new at this :(

Comment: ohhhh i gotcha. @anze's answer is correct; `print_r` is generally used for debugging, not actually displaying data to a user. just loop through `$results` with another `foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this -

```
foreach ($result as $key=>$value){

    //echo Bird Name
    echo "<h3>$key</h3>";

    //start an unordered list
    echo "<ul>";    

    //echo each sighting     
    foreach($value as $row){
        echo "<li>$row</li>";
    }

    //close the unordered list
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: works like a gem, thank you so much! I think I got it from here.

Answer (score 1):

when printing out the result don't use `print_r($result);` use a loop which returns each element in the array! If you need infos on how to display the array as you want to tell us exactly how do you want it to be outputted

Comment: I would like the results echoed out much like they are shown with the name of the bird as an h3 and then the sightings nested underneath...thanks